# java return string from class (linkedhashmap)

Tags: java, string, dictionary, return

Not sure if the title makes sense, but I am trying to return a Success message from a class that receives a linkedhashmap, however eclipse is giving me error when I try to compile the files, offering

`Remove arguments to match 'logFile()'`

`Create constructor 'logFile(Map<String, String>)'`

How do set it up to send a `Map` and revieve a `String`?
thx
Art

Code corrected as per @Jeff Storey below with error suppression for eclipse

calling class

```
 eventLog.put(stringA,stringB);
 logFile logStuff = new logFile();
 successRtn = logFile.Process(eventLog); 
   // Do Stuff with SuccessRtn
```

logFile class

```
 public class  logFile {
    static String Success = "Fail";

  public static String Process(Map<String, String> eventlog){
    // Do Stuff 
    Success = "Yeh!"
    return Success;
   }

  public static void main(String[] args){
  @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
  String result = new logFile().Procces(eventLog);
  System.out.println("result = " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *main* method is a special method whose signature must `public static void main(String[] args)` when being used as an entry point to your application. Create a second method that does the actual work, like this:

```
public class LogFile {

     public String process(Map<String,String> eventLog) {
        // do stuff
        return success;
     }

     public void main(String[] args) {
         // eventLog will probably be read from a filepath passed into the args
        String result = new LogFile().process(eventLog);
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
     }
}
```

Note that a lot of your naming conventions are also non standard. Classes should begin with a capital letter and variables should begin with a lower case.